# Virtual printer driver for MacOS

Tags: macos, printing, swift4, core-services, driverkit

Can I make a virtual printer driver for macOS?

As a service, it's gonna be working on the background and when any user pressed cmd+p to print out any document, mine app will be appearing in the list of printer on the default print out page of Apple.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it could be done, and you don't need a driverkit here.

You could find the code example here: https://sourceforge.net/p/pdfwriterformac/code/HEAD/tree/

This project does exeactly what you need, it's written in C and uses [CUPS](http://web.mit.edu/jhawk/mnt/ss.b/cups-1.4.4/doc/help/api-overview.html) API.

Worth to mention, it is not running like a background service itself, it is instead creates some settings and binary which is used by cupsd system daemon, but this is how it works on macos.

I also think it is possible with some efforts to do the same with Swift, since you added the relevant tag to the question.

Comment: Thanks four your answer Arthur.

I've begun checking the sources you shared. I hope, I can find one more project, source written by swift.